# how to change class of dropdown when select an option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code :

```
<select class="dd-select" name="UM_Status_Engraving" id="UM_Status_Engraving" onchange="colourFunction(this)">
    <option class="dd-select" value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
    <option class="dd-ok" value="OK">OK</option>
    <option class="dd-notok" value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option>
</select>
```

`onchange="colourFunction(this)"` sets a class to dropdown of selected option, it works when I select an option of dropdown, but when I set the option dynamically, it does not call `onchange` so option class does not set to dropdown... some one help...

Comment: How are you setting it dynamically?

Comment: when you call it programmatiacally, also trigger the `change` event programmaticaly on it so that it updates its class.

Comment: Thanx Gabriele , your suggetion works for me...thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the value of the select, also trigger `change()` by yourself.

```js
function colourFunction(ele){
  console.log(ele.value)
}

$('#UM_Status_Engraving').val('OK').trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dd-select" name="UM_Status_Engraving" id="UM_Status_Engraving" onchange="colourFunction(this)">
  <option class="dd-select" value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
  <option class="dd-ok" value="OK">OK</option>
  <option class="dd-notok" value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option>
</select>
```